# Error while deploying ADF application in glassfish

Tags: glassfish, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Hello I am using JDeveloper 11.1.2.3.0
I have configured Glassfish in my computer and I have followed the instructions as Shay explained here: https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/deploying_oracle_adf_applications_to
The problem is that when I try to deploy my ADF application as "Deploy to application server" with glassfish in this case I get an error saying that:

```
[#|2013-08-21T11:45:47.516+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase|_ThreadID=62;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.adf.share.glassfish.listener.ADFGlassFishAppLifeCycleListener
```

If I deploy the ADF aplication as an EAR file and then I try to deploy this EAR file to glassfish through the admin interface I get this other error:

```
[#|2013-08-21T15:40:16.452+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.org.glassfish.deployment.common|_ThreadID=65;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while invoking class com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication start method
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! javax.el.ELContext
```

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 1):

A few things to check-
Did you extract the adf-essentials zip file with the -j option?
Did you mark both your model and view project to have a deployment platform for Glassfish?\

Comment: Thanks for replying , yes I have checked those. I followed your tutorial step-by-step. It is very strange that the error is different when I try to deploy the EAR file directly. Any other suggestion?

Comment: I removed the jar files from /lib/ext and putted el-api.jar by myself in /lib directory. Now I can deploy my application as EAR file without problems but when I try to deploy it directly through JDeveloper the problem is the same:
[#|2013-08-22T09:43:22.507+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase|_ThreadID=98;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:oracle.adf.share.glassfish.listener.ADFGlassFishAppLifeCycleListener

Comment: I do understand that I should have this JAR but I do not know where to find it and where to put then.
Can you help in this point? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that application is deleted from application folder. If not stop-admin server and delete it manually.